How can I (static_)assert that string is not a type?
I am working in an environment with many, many header files, into some of which sometimes a using namespace std; sneaks in. I want to catch (in CI) when that does. It is easy to check that something does exist/compile, but the contrary is surprisingly difficult.
My idea was this:
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
// ...

static_assert(!type_is_defined(string))

How can I write type_is_defined such that it compiles when string is not defined?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai "Do you know how to implement type_is_defined(string)?" No, that is exactly my question. Do you? The key is in "such that it compiles when string is not defined". Whatever implementation of type_is_defined I come up with, they all fail to compile when string is not defined, but that is the case that I need to successfully compile.

I think what you mean is "It is easy to get a compiler error when somethign is not declared", because to actually "check" both cases need to compile, and if you get that then "the contrary" is really just negation via !

This is impossible maybe until reflection is added to C++.

ps: I removed the initial comment, because I think in the meantime I understood what you intend to say

my confusion is from " It is easy to check that something does exist/compile" vs you ask for exactly that ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, well, no. I did not write "It is easy to check if something does exist/compile" (which would be both cases). In other words, I wrote "It is easy to check that something does exist/compile" (simply by writing it), but "It is hard to check that something does not exist/would not compile, all the while ensuring that the code compiles." Does that make more sense now?

as I wrote above, imho "check" implies the result can be negative or positive. Nevermind, I got it.

using string = int; in global namespace would make any use of string without std:: fail with compiler error, though that's a very, very big hack that is likely to backfire. Isn't it simpler to just add another CI job that fails if grep -r "using namespace std;" returns any matches?

you need to at least declare string, then you can check if it is defined. However, all attempts I remember to do that are undefined behavior.

I second @Yksisarvinen.  This is a static analysis job and can be solved by adding another CI step to check if using namespace std; exists in each file. and errors out if it finds it.

This may not be the most elegant way, but it works:
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

//... many headers here, some of which may contain 'using namespace std;'
//using namespace std; //uncommenting it causes compiler error: "reference to 'string' is ambiguous" 

class string;
static_assert(!std::same_as<string, std::string>);

The static_assert requires C++20 because of same_as concept. For C++17, you need to replace it with is_same_v. If you use an earlier C++ version, you can use the following (which works for C++11):
static_assert(!std::is_same<string, std::string>::value, "!");


It's nice, but unfortunately unavailable before C++20 and it will fail if you declare using std::string alone even without incorporating the whole namespace…

@Obsidian it is fine to fail for using std::string, and I am using C++ 20.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, no, if you remove the static_assert, the declaration does not fail even if you uncomment using namespace std

@Eugene oh sorry, my fault, I was experimenting only with using std::string;

Does the static_assert condition do anything?  Just mentioning sizeof(string*) would provoke the ambiguity just as well.

Here's one solution:
#include <string>

// using std::string;
// using namespace std;

// Verify that string is not defined
// Fails with "redeclared as different kind of entity" if "using std::string"
void string() {}
void verify_string_undefined() {
    // Fails with "ambiguous reference" if "using namespace std"
    string();
}

int main() {}

This fails to compile as soon as line 3 or 4 are uncommented.
Unfortunately, this disallows use of using std::string and use of string after the check.

Fortunately this trap need only appear in one translation unit chosen for convenience, such that main or so need not be affected.


I am working in an environment with many, many header files, into some of which sometimes a using namespace std; sneaks in. I want to catch (in CI) when that does.

If this is actually your question, and not specifically about the type string, then you can do this:
#include <charconv>
#include <type_traits>

// Define a non-existent overload of an std::function with a type that can be converted from the actual signature
// Make sure to use a different return type
static int to_chars( char*, char*, bool ){return 0;}
 
int main() {
    // using namespace std; static assert will fail with this in place

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,
    // Make sure to use the type for the std:: signature here, 
    // not your custom function's converted type. So 1.0f and not true
    decltype(to_chars(std::declval<char*>(),std::declval<char*>(),1.0f))
    >, "using namespace std when we should not be");
}


You could just use ... to make your overload worse than any other.
